# Parsing FQN of enum constant to enum constant w/o splitting the string

Tags: c#, parsing, command-line, enums, command-line-arguments

Trying to parse an commandline argument ( 'MyNameSpace.MyEnumClassName.MyConstantName') in order to get the constant.

Is this possible without extracting the EnumClassName? I know that I could get the constant with 
`Type.GetType(...);
Enum.Parse(...)`

But is there a direct way?

Background:
This argument can be used for different things. There can be a fqn of a class, a constant, ... I know it's not kind of 'clean', but that`s not part of this question.

Comment: I think it is not possible because `Enum.Parse()` requires the type of enum to be parsed.

Comment: You mean you want to get a string `"MyConstantName"`? `arg.Split('.').Last()` if you want the enum instance / numeric value, you need to `Enum.Parse()`

Comment: Surely Type.GetType on the MyNameSpace.MyEnumClassName followed by the Enum.Parse on the MyConstantName will get you the Enum Value in an Object. That's not particularly heavy going. If you want it as a single function, then write a static function in a utility class somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I want MyConstantName but not the String, the constant object in c#. And don't want string-operations as this argument should be usable for other classes/objects... The constant is just one option. Yes, it's ugly but at least it shouldn`t be more ugly by having to split the string in some cases :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there seems to be no direct way, I close this question with the answer "**no**".